# Adding transition to different lines in a line chart d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a line chart with two lines called in this way

```
svg.append("path")
               .attr("class","line")
               .attr("d",line1(data))
               .style("stroke","blue");

          svg.append("path")
               .attr("id",'tag2')
               .attr("d",line2(data))
               .style("stroke","red");
```

and I want to add the same transition to both of the lines,the transition is the following

```
transition().duration(2500).attrTween("d",pathTween);
           function pathTween() {
                var interpolate = d3.scale.quantile()
                                    .domain([0,1])
                                    .range(d3.range(1, data.length + 1));
                return function(t) {
                    return line(data.slice(0, interpolate(t)));
                };
            }
```

in practice this one has the effect of drawing the line on the chart,how can i call it to draw both of the lines? thanks!

Comment: Can you pls add your working code on http://jsfiddle.net/. It's tough to run test cases from your code snippet as line1(data), line2(data) functions are not available. Thanks

Comment: how can I import my external data on jsfiddle? I've never used jsfiddle!however the building of the graph is correct,but i can't add a transition.If you tell me how to import my data sources on jsfiddle I'll provide to load my code on it :) @adnan

Comment: here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/oe5qbct9/   but i don't know how to link my file so here is the file  http://wikisend.com/download/732088/difference.tsv]difference.tsv if you can try by yourself,just because I don't know how to manage this file in jsfiddle =) thanks @adnan

Comment: Sorry jsfiddle is not the right place for this purpose. From d3 Examples page they have already said how to share a d3 example easily. Here is how: 1) Create a GitHub Gist (I created a test one here: https://gist.github.com/abm-adnan) 2) From http://bl.ocks.org/ point it to your username (for example: http://bl.ocks.org/abm-adnan). On gist you can add your data files. :)

Comment: Your html file must be named `index.html` https://gist.github.com/abm-adnan/e6e3017ae2272632aca0

Comment: I've done the Gist on gitHub https://gist.github.com/mirko4 but from bl.ocks.org when I point to my username,I do not get anything :o what's wrong with me?ahah Edit: now I see my things on bl.ocks  http://bl.ocks.org/mirko4  and now? @adnan

Comment: I've managed to run your code on my localhost. Are you looking for this kind of transition() http://blog.visual.ly/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/transitions.html#13

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've done it!

> http://bl.ocks.org/abm-adnan/raw/cb1ece4b962ac3770325/
>
> http://bl.ocks.org/abm-adnan/cb1ece4b962ac3770325
>
> https://gist.github.com/abm-adnan/cb1ece4b962ac3770325

My modifications are here:

```
graphmen = svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("id", 'tag1')
    //.attr("d", line1(data))
    .style("stroke", "blue");

/* svg.append("text").text("Men").attr("transform",function(d){
    "translate("+xScale(d.anno)+","+yScale(d.uomo)+")";
}) ; */
graphmen.transition().duration(2000).attrTween("d",pathTween1);
function pathTween1() {
    var interpolate = d3.scale.quantile()
        .domain([0, 1])
        .range(d3.range(1, data.length + 1));
    return function(t) {
        return line1(data.slice(0, interpolate(t)));
    };
}


graphwomen = svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("id", 'tag2')
   // .attr("d", line2(data))
    .style("stroke", "red");

graphwomen.transition().duration(2000).attrTween("d",pathTween2);
function pathTween2() {
    var interpolate = d3.scale.quantile()
        .domain([0, 1])
        .range(d3.range(1, data.length + 1));
    return function(t) {
        return line2(data.slice(0, interpolate(t)));
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanksssss ;) You deserve a coffee :p

Comment: My pleasure! Please select my answer as `accepted answer`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use a custom tween function that knows how to interpolate point:

## Code

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr({
        "width": 700,
        "height": 500,
    });
var array = [
    [100, 100],
    [150, 150],
    [200, 100],
    [250, 150],
    [300, 100],
    [350, 150]
]; 
var line = d3.svg.line();
line.interpolate("monotone");
Draw_();
setInterval(function(){
    d3.select('svg').html('');
    Draw_();
},2500)
function Draw_(){
    var path_ = svg.append('path')
    .attr({
        "transform": "translate(0,0)"
    })
    .style({
        "stroke": "steelblue",
        "stroke-width": 5,
        "fill": "none"
    })
    path_
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attrTween("d", function(d) {
            return lineTween.call(this, array)
        })
}

function lineTween(b) {
        var num = array.length;
        var arr_ = [];
        for(var i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
           arr_.push(1 / num * i)
        }
        return function(t) {
            var i = 0
            while(arr_[i] < t) {
                i++;
            }
            var new_arr = interpolateArrays(i, t)
            function interpolateArrays(index, time, array) {
                index--;
                if(!array) array = b;
                var fixed_arr = array.slice(0, index);
                var current_arr = array.slice(index, index + 2);
                var line_interpolate = d3.interpolate([current_arr[0], current_arr[0]], current_arr);
                var r = arr_.slice(index, index + 2)
                var scale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain(r)
                    .range([0, 1]);
                var slice_arr = line_interpolate(scale(t));
                return d3.merge([fixed_arr, slice_arr])
            }
            return line(new_arr)
       }
   }
   </script>
```

Comment: Can you add explanation about your solution?

Comment: I'm sorry;English is not my native language

Comment: The solution is to use a custom tween function that knows how to interpolate point: